# Simple way for async/event driven request Ruby on Rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events, asynchronous

I am trying to implement a simple solution to help with some behavior. Basically I want to create a listener on a particular url, like

```
    localhost:3000/listen
```

I have a callback with a 3rd party service that is sending JSON as a post request.  In my rails routes I have the route setup, to accept a post request to that namespace.

The thing that I want to happen, is for some logic to be run anytime a new post comes in and to run that logic async without any disruption to the normal web service.  For example,  the post request will contain some data, if the data has a boolean "true", we need to fire off a Rails Mailer.   I normally could do this with a simple rails controller action but this is not correct.

Any thoughts on the best approach to handle this?  Would this best with a gem like eventmachine? If anyone could give their feedback to implement a simple solution that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at your background jobs. I am a [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) fan, and popular alternatives are [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) and [DelayedJob](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job).

Your controller will receive the response, and schedule it to be performed in the background. That will send out the mail (or whatever you need it to do) asynchronously.

```
class CallbackController < ApplicationController


  def listen_third_party
    data = params.slice([:params, :you, :care, :about])
    if data[:boolean_field] == true
      CallbackMailer.perform_async(data)
    end
  end

end
```